# The rendering of some combined UTF-8 emoji characters seems to be messed up on Super User when using Safari

Tags: support, bug, emoji

I am using macOS 13 (Ventura). Preface to this is I am not a big fan of the use of emojis on SE sites, but this seems like a bug to me.

Please look at [this Super User question](https://superuser.com/q/1759323). Note that in an area where the original poster added more details, such as their two clumsy cats causing a hard drive failure, they use these Emojis: ‍⬛

When I load that page in Firefox (108.0.1 - 64-bit), it looks like this:

> [image]

But when I load it in Safari (16.2 - 18614.3.7.1.5) it looks like this; note how the second cat is the plain orange/white emoji cat followed by a black box:

> [image]

I can see the [black cat](https://emojipedia.org/black-cat/) and [orange/white cat](https://emojipedia.org/cat/) fine when I visit Emojipedia. Just not on Super User with Safari.

Is this a known issue with combined UTF-8 emojis? Checking these characters out with [an online UTF-8 character inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%90%88%F0%9F%90%88%E2%80%8D%E2%AC%9B) shows no obvious issues to my eyes; then again I don’t code or manage the way SE sites handle UTF-8 charaters so hey!

Screenshot below of the two cats being rendered properly in Safari (16.2 - 18614.3.7.1.5) with the text area of [the UTF-8 character inspector mentioned above](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%90%88%F0%9F%90%88%E2%80%8D%E2%AC%9B).

> [image]

And here is a screenshot of those two cats if I click on “Disable Styles” from the “Develop” menu in Safari; they render 100% fine!

> [image]

And here is me hacking the DOM to wrap the cat emoji in this span with inline CSS styles that forces the use of the “Apple Color Emoji” font family:

```
<span style="font-family: Apple Color Emoji;">‍⬛</span>
```

And lo and behold, it renders cleanly when I do this! See screenshot below.

But of course this is not a final solution since not everyone is using macOS systems. But it at least proves there might be a typeface issue in play here.

> [image]

Comment: Well that looks more like a problem with Safari not handling the way the black cat is represented using 3 unicode code points rather than a Stack Exchange problem. It looks like it hasn't dealt with the U+200d "zero width joiner" properly.

Comment: I see the same black rectangle in Chrome latest, PC, Windows 10. So it's not Safari, it's something more basic, maybe some fancy font missing.